# how to lookup approximate in DataFrame Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a lab with 2 dataframes as below:

```
df1 = df1.head(10)
        HT  D
    0   A   BL
    1   B   0
    2   C   NaN
    3   D   7
    4   E   3
    5   F   NaN
    6   G   2


rng.head(10)
    Range   Group
0   0       group A
1   3       Group B
2   5       Group C
3   8       Group D
4   11      Group E
```

how I can find approximate value from column df['D'] in column rng['Range'] , sth like vlookup approximate in Excel.
My output expected as below:

```
    HT  D    Group
0   A   BL   
1   B   0    GroupA
2   C   NaN
3   D   7    GroupC
4   E   3    GroupB
5   F   NaN  
6   G   2    GroupA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `merge_asof` to create an intermediate, then join on the index. Your particular case is made more complex as you have mixed types in 'D', so you first need to subselect the numbers.

```
s = pd.to_numeric(df1['D'], errors='coerce')
df2 = pd.merge_asof(s[s.notna()].astype(int).reset_index(), rng,
                    left_on='D', right_on='Range')

out = df1.join(df2.drop(columns='D').set_index('index'))
```

output:

```
  HT    D  Range    Group
0  A   BL    NaN      NaN
1  B    0    0.0  group A
2  C  NaN    NaN      NaN
3  D    2    0.0  group A
4  E    3    3.0  Group B
5  F  NaN    NaN      NaN
6  G    7    5.0  Group C
```

Comment: Hi @mozway, thank you for your assist , I tried but i got the error "MergeError: incompatible merge keys [0] dtype('int32') and dtype('int64'), must be the same type" :( .

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, so use whatever type make it common: `astype('int64')` for example

Comment: Hi @mozway , if the dataset isn't orderly arrange , your solution will get error "ValueError: left keys must be sorted" , how you do the sort in column 'D' include str and number in this case ?

Comment: `merge_asof` requires both keys to be sorted. Use `sort_values`: `s[s.notna()].astype(int).sort_values().reset_index()` and `rng.sort_values(by='Range')`

Comment: thank you , i have sorted in the first line , s = pd.to_numeric(df1['D'], errors='coerce').sort_values() , it also work as well. Thank you so much Bro , have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function that returns the closest group for a given value of `d` and then use that to assign a group to every row in df1

```
def find_group(d):
    if np.isnan(d):
        return ''
    return rng.iloc[(rng['Range']-d).abs().argmin()]['Group']
```

```
df2 = df1.copy()
df2['Group'] = pd.to_numeric(df2['D'], errors='coerce').apply(lambda x: find_group(x))
```

This produces the output:

```
>>> print(df2)
  HT    D   Group
0  A   BL        
1  B    0  groupA
2  C  NaN        
3  D    2  GroupB
4  E    3  GroupB
5  F  NaN        
6  G    7  GroupD
```

EDIT: I believe the Excel lookup doesn't match the closest row but rather the largest value that is less than the lookup value. You can implement that logic in the `find_group` function as well:

```
def find_group(d):
    if np.isnan(d):
        return ''
    return rng[(d >= rng['Range'])].iloc[-1]['Group']
```

Comment: Thank you @Ani, I also tried this function , this logic work fine in this case